# how to create a modal popup with a jQgrid in it?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am looking for a simple ASP.NET MVC 3 sample of how to implement a modal window with a jqgrid?
So I would like to open a popup first and then display the grid in the popup.
Has anyone come across this before ?

Comment: before pasting please google properly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587480/jquery-modal-dialog-and-jqgrid   and this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725272/jqgrid-and-popup-modal-windows-from-link will help you, you should check these links first and implement something, if it doesn't work out then ask questions

Comment: take one step at a time.. are you able to implement a modal window first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is the simplest implementation of a modal window that I know of.  You should be able to put whatever you want in side it.